# Obtener valor de un objeto JSON de acuerdo al valor de otro objeto JSON

Tags: javascript

**Transfondo:**

Tengo una aplicación en VB.NET donde consumo algunos servicios web "API's". Uno de estos API *(para efectos de la pregunta se llamará `EnviarArchivo`)* retorna un objeto con esta estructura:

Respuesta de la API `EnviarArchivo`:

```
[{
    "DocumentType": "SalesInvoice",
    "CreationDate": "2019-01-02T15:26:00.041Z",
    "DocumentDate": "2018-10-17T00:00:00",
    "DueDate": "2018-10-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Currency": "COP",
    "BusinessStatus": "Certified",
    "CommunicationStatus": "DeliverOk",
    "MainNotificationEmailStatus": "Delivered",
    ...
}]
```

Tengo una variable global llamada "traduccionRespuestasAPI" cuyo valor es un objeto JSON con esta estructura:

Variable global `traduccionRespuestasAPI`:

```
var traduccionRespuestasAPI = {
    "Cancel": "Cancelar",
    "Categories": "Categorias",
    "Certified": "Certificado",
    "CitizenshipCard": "Tarjeta Ciudadanía",
    "Delireved": "Entregado",
    "Delivered": "Entregado",
    "DeliverOk": "Entrega Exitosa",
    "Description_Label": "Descripción",
    "Received": "Recibido",
    "Registered": "Registrado",
    "Reject": "Rechazar",
    ...
};
```

**Problema:**

Lo que busco es que *"de acuerdo a la respuesta de la API `EnviarArchivo`"* consulte la variable global `traduccionRespuestasAPI` y establezca el valor.

Ejemplo:

Si la respuesta de la API `EnviarArchivo`en el campo "BusinessStatus" fue "Certified", debe buscar en la variable global `traduccionRespuestasAPI` el atributo con nombre "Certified" y mostrar el valor "Certificado".

Sin usar bucles, ¿cómo acceder al valor de la variable local según la respuesta de la API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que el valor de la respuesta del API siempre va a estar presente en tu objeto traducciones, puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var EnviarArchivo = [{
    "DocumentType": "SalesInvoice",
    "CreationDate": "2019-01-02T15:26:00.041Z",
    "DocumentDate": "2018-10-17T00:00:00",
    "DueDate": "2018-10-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Currency": "COP",
    "BusinessStatus": "Certified",
    "CommunicationStatus": "DeliverOk",
    "MainNotificationEmailStatus": "Delivered"
}];

var traduccionRespuestasAPI = {
    "Cancel": "Cancelar",
    "Categories": "Categorias",
    "Certified": "Certificado",
    "CitizenshipCard": "Tarjeta Ciudadanía",
    "Delireved": "Entregado",
    "Delivered": "Entregado",
    "DeliverOk": "Entrega Exitosa",
    "Description_Label": "Descripción",
    "Received": "Recibido",
    "Registered": "Registrado",
    "Reject": "Rechazar"
};

console.log(traduccionRespuestasAPI[EnviarArchivo[0]["BusinessStatus"]]);
```